# External images not showing under apache

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have two virtual systems for development. First one is Windows + xampp (apache, php, mysql) and second one is Linux + apache + php + mysql. I have very very simple page that loads images from database (yes, images are in the database not on the filesystem, it is not the case here, is it right or not) using external links.

The first page shows photos:

```
<img src="photo.php?photo_id=4" height="127" width="127">
```

The second page loads them from database:

```
if (isset($_GET['photo_id'])) {
    $link = getDBconnection();
    $result = getPhoto($link, $_GET['photo_id']);

    if ($result) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        header("Content-type: " . $row['MIMEtype']);
        echo $row['photoImage'];
    }

    closeDBconnection($link);
}
```

Everything is working fine on the Windows machine but on the linux machine, pictures just don't show up. I mean image files from page directory loads up and shows up but somehow this external link stopped working. I've places few echos and for sure script executes and photoImage has binary data.

I wonder, is it just configuration issue (probable, am not configuring apache/php/mysql every day). I've stuck at that point. Any ideas?

PS. Database is exactly the same. I've just exported/imported it from Windows to Linux mysql database. Any other data is successfully selected from database. It's just the photos, that don't work.

**SOLVED**
Thanks Marc B for the tip about encoding. I was aware of the possible issue but completely forgot about it. After copying the files once more time to the LINUX machine via ftp, and after double checking that I did not change encoding (by editing any file), the photos showed up.

Comment: When outputtnig the image from the DB have you set the header in photo.php to the correct image type for the image? i.e. jpeg, png..etc

Comment: Yes, headers are set to 'image/jpeg' using $row['MIMEtype']. The MIME type is stored as an attribute inside the photo table.

Comment: Are you testing in the same browser?

Comment: did you try opening the "photo.php?photo_id=4 in your browser directly? Does that work?

Comment: Yes, I am mainly focused on getting it working using direct link. On windows machine, am using Mozilla and Opera (www/mysql as a service, localhost pages). Linux on the other hand is a "remote machine", with hosting services (forgot to mention that). Am displaying pages from Linux in my host machine (hosting those two virtual machines) using Chrome and Opera. Both of them cannot show the image using direct photo.php link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

1. Check for database errors - you say the photoImage field has binary data, so not likely, but never ever assume a database call succeeded
2. Check for early text output, causing the header() call to fail - it should be getting logged somewhere. Turn on display_errors/error_logging while developing, in any case, so you don't have to rummage around in logs to find out what's going wrong.
3. Hit the url manually in a browser and see what comes through. Perhaps there's some characterset translation going causing the image data to be corrupted (e.g. you're using a TEXT field instead of a BLOB).

Comment: Is 'if (!mysql_error($result)) {}' enough to be sure that database call succeeded? Thanks for the tip with errors, I set up additional 'error_reporting(E_ALL);' at the beginning of the script, but no errors showed up. Finally, there was some issue with encoding. I have copied files one more time and double checked if the encoding is the same. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: `if ($result === false) { die(mysql_error()) }` is the simplest error check. But if this script is only ever loaded via `<img>` tags, then the error output text would be interpreted as a corrupt image, and you might want to instead output a placeholder picture instead.

Comment: Isn't 'if ($result)' equal to 'if ($result === false)' ??

Comment: usually. but the === version is a strict check for a boolean false. The other version can give a false result if $result is an empty string or a 0 - php maps quite a few non "empty" values to be equivalent to a 0/false value.